# Dynamically show bootstrap's surrounding error div on ValidationSummary?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, html-helper

I have a ASP .NET MVC 4.5 that uses Razor View Engine. I also added Bootstrap to it.

**My doubt is**: How do I dynamically show or hide a div according to the @Html.ValidationSummary()? - preferably without JQuery.

In my specific case, there's a form which contains several inputs. Whenever a validation error occours (eg. empty field), I intend to show the associated error message in a single div.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger">
@Html.ValidationSummary();
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the built-in ControlToValidate ?

Comment: I am not that sure about your question (ControlToValidate). 

The form contains inputs, these inputs are generated using the @Html.InputFor (x => model.property).

The validation itself is fine, it happens as expected. 

The matter here is that: How can I show a <div> just when the @Html.ValidatioSummary() has errors.

Comment: Why isent it sufficient to use @Html.ValidationSummary("Your message", new{@class="alert alert-danger"})?

Comment: No success by using the way you said @helgeheldre

The Summary appears within the DIV (reddish one), though what I need is to show this DIV (containing the ValidationSummary) ONLY when some field validator error occours.

Answer (score 24):

This is all built into MVC no reason for any sort of hacking.

Simply use:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "alert alert-danger" })
```

Assitionally some CSS to hide it when there are no errors:

```
.validation-summary-valid.alert-danger {
    display: none;
}
```

Much easier, much cleaner.

Comment: and works with client side validation where the other solution falls down

Comment: Just a quick correction: `.validation-summary-valid.alert-danger.alert-danger` should be `.validation-summary-valid.alert.alert-danger`.

Comment: Where am I suppose to add the CSS?

Comment: This is superior than other solutions

Answer (score 4):

I would use an html helper which you could call like this:

```
         @Html.BootStrapValidationSummary();
```

Here is the code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootStrapValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
     var sb = new StringBuilder();

     var anyErrors = ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where( v => v.Errors.Count != 0 ).Any();
     var divBeginTag = @"<div class=""alert alert-danger"">";
     var divEndTag = @"</div>";

     if (anyErrors) {
         sb.AppendLine(divBeginTag);
         sb.AppendLine(htmlHelper.ValidationSummary());         
         sb.AppendLine(divEndTag);
         return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
     } 
     else
     {
       return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
     }


}
```

This is a quicker way but feels like a hack (I personally hate using if statements in views):

```
 @{
    var anyErrors = ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where( v => v.Errors.Count != 0 ).Any();
 }

@if (anyErrors) {
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
  @Html.ValidationSummary();
</div>
}
```

Comment: I think you should surround all AppendLine(...) statements in a {} or you would always try to populate the stringbuilder wich seems a bit unneccessary. In fact you could return from the method early if no error are detected.

Comment: Hi @hutchonoid, I did not have a chance to apply your code yet.

Regarding it, you're "suggesting" to modify the BootStrapValidationSummary method? 

By doing so, would not it progapate some side effect?

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, no side effect. It is a new extension method that it will create, not modify.

Comment: I could not find out where to place the BootStrapValidationSummary method. I tried to create a Helper (class) but no success.

Comment: It needs to go in a static class with the name space as System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: No deal at all! The static class (that uses the suggested namespace above) could not find the ViewData nor htmlHelper.ValidationSummary().

Comment: You need to include the relevant namespace imports too. Have you never created an HtmlHelper extension before? I have used this code many times and never ran into problems but I use html helpers everywhere.

Comment: The view data is already in the class, type htmlHelper.ViewData from within the method to access it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.viewdata(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: This is an article on how to create the helpers, it uses mvc2 but apart from not using razor it is very relevant still. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs

Comment: @GuilhermeCalegari please see my answer below, there is no need to resort to additional code, it's all do-able within the MVC framework.

Comment: For MVC5: In order to use ValidationSummary() on `htmlHelper`, you have to include `System.Web.Mvc.Html`. It's an extension method defined there.